# colors and title in Pie charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: I need to build this]
[image: I have such result now]
I have such code now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
a = dataset['PassengerId'][dataset['Survived'] == 0].count()
b = dataset['PassengerId'][dataset['Survived'] == 1].count()
labels = [0,1]
vals = [a,b]
exp = (0.1, 0.0)
ax.pie(vals, labels=labels, autopct='%.1f', explode=exp, shadow="True")
```

I need to set a title and change colors on both axes(as on example) and set percents for values on each wedge i dont know how to do this

I was trying to find videos which could help me

Answer (score 0):

To set the title:

```
ax.set_title('Survived')
```

Add `%%` to your format string (resulting in `%.1f%%`) that you're using as the `autopct` argument to add percent signs to labels:

```
ax.pie(vals, labels=labels, autopct='%.1f%%', explode=exp, shadow="True")
```

(The double `%%` is an "escaped" `%`)

I'm not sure what you were looking for in terms of colors, as the standard color cycle seems close to what you're looking for, but you can use the [`colors` keyword argument](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) to specify colors.

For example, from the image you posted:

```
colors=['#4c72b0', '#dd8452']
```

**Full code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
a = 616
b = 384
labels = [0,1]
vals = [a,b]
exp = (0.1, 0.0)
ax.pie(
    vals, 
    labels = labels, 
    autopct = '%.1f%%', 
    explode = exp, 
    shadow = "True", 
    colors = ['#4c72b0', '#dd8452'],
)
ax.set_title('Survived')

plt.show()
```

[image]